# How to receive message from the asp.net core using signalR core to UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, asp.net-core-signalr

SignalR core was demo with javascript client or Angular
My case is using UWP to render the front-end. While Microsoft only tell how to Invoke the message from client to server, It's docs didn't show how to receive message 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2][1]

Here is my server:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        services.AddSingleton<IInventoryServices, InventoryServices>();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseSignalR(route =>
        {
            route.MapHub<MessageHub>("/hub");
        });

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

this is the controller:

```
[Route("api/hub")]
[ApiController]
public class MessController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<MessageHub> _messhubContext;

    public MessController(IHubContext<MessageHub> messhubContext)
    {
        _messhubContext = messhubContext;
    }

    public ActionResult Post()
    {
        _messhubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("send", "Strypper", "Howdy");
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("I'm here");
        return Ok();
    }
```

And here is the hub:

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string user ,string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", user, message);
    }
}
```

My "PostMan" is messed up and I don't wanna discuss about it. Is there anyone here work with uwp framework could show me the way to receive the message from the server I made ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I originally misunderstood and turned it around.

For communication for server to client, you have to follow the [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2#call-client-methods-from-hub).

You need to define a listener in UWP like this:

```
connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
{
   //do something
});
```

And send the message on server side like this:

```
await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user,message);
```

### Previous answer

To invoke a `Hub` method from client, you can use the `InvokeAsync` method:

```
await connection.InvokeAsync("MyMethod", "someparameter");
```

Then you just create the method in the `Hub` class

```
public class MessageHub : Hub
{
    public Task Send(string user ,string message)
    {
        return Clients.All.SendAsync("Send", user, message);
    }

    public Task MyMethod(string parameter)
    {
        //do something here
    }
}
```

There is also an overload of `InvokeAsync<TResult>` that allows you to create a method with a return type.